# Set Crystal Report's datasource to a class from .dll

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am using C#, Visual Studio 2008 and Framework 2.0.

I have two projects in my solution- a winform project and a class library. I have added a crystal report file to the winform project. But can not set its datasource to the custom objects in class library. I also have added objects from class library using "Data-> Add New Data Source".

In crystal report, Database Fields-> Database Expert->.Net Objects does not show my custom objects.

Is there any solution ??

Regards, SKPaul

Answer (score 3):

You can get the data objects to show up by adding a crystal report to the class library, then creating connections to the data objects from the database expert of that report. When you go back to the app and pull up the database expert of the report, the connections should be there. They show up under "My Connections" rather than under "Project Data.NET Objects", but you should still be able to add them to the report.